# Angular 1/JavaScript delete property object as if it never existed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, object, lodash

I want to delete a property object as if it never existed, the solution of void operator (void 0) and delete operator march but I would like another alternative using lodash for example.

My case :

```
//variable
this.project.monthlyRent = void 0
//Object
this.project.TypeChoose =  void 0
```

Comment: you can use for variable  this.project.monthlyRent =  undefined; and for object this.project.TypeChoose =  {};

Comment: @Shohel Yes it works, another alternative?

Comment: [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) this.project.montlyRent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**delete** operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), although I don't particular recommend using that alternative. If you do use it, you need to be aware of it's limitations and how it behaves if you're using strict mode.

If you instead want an immutable alternative, you can use, like you say, lodash. What you'd do then is use `_.omit` (for creating a new object with the given properties omitted) or `_.pick` (for creating a new object with only the given properties included). Like this:

```
var obj = {
    firstname: "Nikolaj",
    lastname :"Larsen",
    age:99
};
var result = _.omit(obj , ['age']); 
// result: { firstname: .., lastname: .. }
```

and

```
var obj = {
    firstname: "Nikolaj",
    lastname :"Larsen",
    age:99
};
var result = _.pick(obj , ['firstname', 'lastname']); 
// result: { firstname: .., lastname: .. }
```

Like said, it's immutable so it doesn't change the old object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Example 1**

```
//variable
this.project.monthlyRent = undefined;
//Object
this.project.TypeChoose =  {};
```

**Example 2**

```
//variable
delete this.project.monthlyRent;

//Object
delete this.project.TypeChoose;
```